# Lookup field formatted value from Web API in Microsoft Dynamics CRM is undefined (cannot get formatted value)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I’m using http request to get value of the lookup field, and I can’t get it formatted `result["_log_postalcode_value"]` - shows "ff4c33be-5139-e211-bd26-e41f13be0af4", but `result["_log_postalcode_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]` - is undefined. I struggling to find out whats wrong in my code, also tried to google but no answers. Maybe somebody could help me.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("GET", window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts(" + guid + ")?$select=_log_postalcode_value", false);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"); 
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {          
        req.onreadystatechange = null;   
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);             
            console.log(result["_log_postalcode_value"]);//shows "ff4c33be-5139-e211-bd26-e41f13be0af4"
            console.log(result["_log_postalcode_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]); // shows undefined
```

Comment: I don’t see any issue in code. Build & test the code using CRM REST Builder, May be give a try with the new Xrm.Webapi methods. Check the entity privilege or try another attribute (picklist or lookup). Switch the “Prefer” header to use “*” as well

Comment: I tried to use "*" in the "Prefer" header and check other lookup fields bus unfortunately getting the same issue.

Comment: can you test in some trial instance & troubleshoot your environmental behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try CRM Rest builder and see what output you receive.
I just tried your usecase in one of my Trail Instance and it worked for me

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts(DC86C293-CA4F-E911-A82F-000D3A385A1C)?$select=accountid,_crmp_languagecode_value", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var accountid = result["accountid"];
            var _crmp_languagecode_value = result["_crmp_languagecode_value"];
            var _crmp_languagecode_value_formatted = result["_crmp_languagecode_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var _crmp_languagecode_value_lookuplogicalname = result["_crmp_languagecode_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

and here is the output I received

```
{

    @odata.context:"[ORGURL]/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(accountid,_crmp_languagecode_value)/$entity",
    @odata.etag:"W/"3139254"",
    accountid:"dc86c293-ca4f-e911-a82f-000d3a385a1c",
    _crmp_languagecode_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue:"FR",
    _crmp_languagecode_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty:"crmp_languagecode",
    _crmp_languagecode_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname:"crmp_languagecode",
    _crmp_languagecode_value:"78a6bb04-88db-e811-a961-000d3ab42b3b"

}
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately same issue. What i discovered that my object doesn't return formatted values as yours, only simple field value (last line in your response)

Comment: {@odata.context: "https://intmscrmtst.sectoralarm.net/SectorAlarmfrtst/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(name,_log_postalcode_value,emailaddress1,log_dateofbirth,accountid)/$entity"
@odata.etag: "W/"21485521""
accountid: "223467e7-943f-e911-80ed-005056a67c5e"
emailaddress1: null
log_dateofbirth: null
name: ". INDIVISION  CAZENAVE"
_log_postalcode_value: "867bbca7-59ee-e811-80ea-005056a626f7"
__proto__: Object}

Comment: Well I tried in plan JS, and it actually worked fine. I didn't mention that I implemented this function in react then build it with webpack and finally deployed as web resource in CRM. I didn't thing that React could have any impact as it is JS library, but yes it differs and it is a cause i believe.

Comment: Ahh so in Normal Js it does work but not from react.

Comment: Exactly, works in normal JS but not in React. Any ideas how could i fix it? Or maybe another question, does React support it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'expand' property.

Here is the official document from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api#bkmk_lookupProperty